# Detecting a "zone exit" with iBeacon

Tags: ibeacon

After how many time the iBeacon stack is deciding that the user is exiting a zone covered by an iBeacon ?
By example, if my beacon is advertising 10 times/s during 5s and stops during 15s is an "exit zone" event fired ?
What is the limit without signal to not send an "exit zone" event ? 5s ? 2s ?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer: 3 seconds.**  If iOS goes 3 seconds without seeing an iBeacon in a scan, it will fire an exit region event.

**Long answer:** If your app is in the background or if it is not ranging in the foreground, iOS will not be doing constant Bluetooth scans to look for iBeacons.  The period between scans can be up to 15 minutes, so it is possible that your region exit event could come as much as 15:03 after the iBeacon is no longer seen.

See details on these measurements here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/03/12/ios7-1-background-detection-times.html